# How to keep track of old versions of objects in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I was working on a project on ASP.NET Core where I had to keep track of edits to Contracts here is where I've come so far,
Models -

```
  //Contract Model
  public class Contract
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ContractId { get; set; }
    }




//Contrat History Model
   public class ContratEditHistory
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Edited By")]
        public string EditorId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("EditorId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public int ContratId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ContractId")]
        public virtual Contract Contrat { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 255)]
        public string ChangeReason { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateEdited { get; set; }

    }
```

This seems to work fine in logging who made changes to a contract but I want to "store" the previous version of the contract when the contract is updated so users will be able to look up what changes were made. How can I achieve that?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. You could use event sourcing to construct your objects, or aggregates. You could do something as simple as having a second table which simply stores 1 previous contract revision before the current.

Comment: SQL Server also has a built-in change tracking feature now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: In the ContratEditHistory model, you could add a property to store the change detail (for example, use a Description property and store the history "change `ContractId` from 'A' to 'B'"). Or add two properties in the ContratEditHistory model and store the OldValue and NewValue, you could also create new a table to store these properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object versioning can get very complicated. Depending on the complexity of the data you are versioning, and where you are storing it, there may be an easy solution for it. As mentioned in the comments, SQL Server has built-in version tracking for rows in a table. In my experience, these types of solutions work well in some cases, but in general, don't scale well. I would recommend implementing something similar to the "Memento" software pattern for persisting the state of the "Contract" record. In this software pattern, there are three objects, Caretaker, Originator, and Memento.

- Caretaker: this would probably be your controller
- Originator: this object is responsible for creating and restoring versions of the "contract" entity
- Memento: this object saves the state of the contract where ever you want to store it. I would recommend using your existing edit history class and just serialized the contract to JSON and storing it in the table

You would add classes like the following for your application:

```
//Contrat History Model
public class ContratEditHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Edited By")]
    public string EditorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EditorId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int ContratId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContractId")]
    public virtual Contract Contrat { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 255)]
    public string ChangeReason { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateEdited { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String SeralizedData { get; set; }
}

//Originator
public class ContractOriginator
{
    public ContractEditHistory CreateVersion(string changeReason, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        // create the ContractEditHistory object and save it
    }
    public Contract RestoreVersion(ContractEditHistory version)
    {
        // restore a ContractEditHistory as the current Contract 
    }
    public List<ContractEditHistory> GetVersions(Contract contract)
    {
        // a helper function to list all the versions for a contract
    }
}
```

As the "Contract" object gets more complex, you may need to expand this out and consider alternative methods of storing the version rather than just serializing it to to a column as in this simple example. Your mileage will vary, good luck! Checkout Wikipedia for more info about this pattern.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern